# Set views delegate to be something other than self

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to set a views delegate to something other that self.

[image: Example Screen Shot]

I basically want to make 'Master View' a delegate of 'Second Modal'. Since I'm using storyboards I assume that can set the delegate of 'Second Modal' on the segue from 'First Modal' to 'Second Modal'.  I just can't seem to make this happen.

I already have methods in 'Master View' waiting for 'Second Modal' view to call as due to design reasons I have had to add 'First Modal'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set the delegate property in code.

In the implementation of the view controller who's view you want to delegate (in your case "Second Modal") just call:

```
self.(whatever view has the delegate property).delegate = [self.presentingViewcontroller.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController]
```

Or something along those lines depending on your setup.

Every modal view controller has a back pointer to its presenting view controller.

Every viewController embedded in a navigationController has a back pointer to the navigationController.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer but I can't seem to get this to work

Comment: What are you trying to delegate? Does your master view implement the required protocols?

Comment: That's usually just some bad syntax like an extra set of brackets or a missing @end or something.. look above and below the troubled line of code.